# Entity & Entity Properties. Database design for effective searching

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, database-design, database-performance

Last two days i've been searching suitable solution for the problem described below.

In my standalone *notification-service* module I have an abstract *Message* entity. *Message* has 'to', 'from', 'sentAt', 'receivedAt' and other attributes. The responsibility of the notification-service is to:

1. send new messages using different registered message providers (SMS, EMAIL, Skype , etc).
2. receive new messages from registered message providers
3. update status for already sent messages.

*Notification-service* module is developed as standalone module that is available by SOAP protocol. A lot of clients can use this module to send or searching through already received messages.

Clients want to attach some properties (~ smth like tags) while sending messages for further searching messages by these properties. These properties make a sense only in client's environment.

For example, *Client A* might want to send message and save following custom properties :
1. Internal system id of user whom system sends message
2. Distinguish flag  (whether id related to users / admins or clients)
3. Notification flag (notification/alert/ ...)

*Client B* might want to send message and save another set of custom properties : 
1. Internal system operator id (who sends sms)
2. Template id that was used to send message

Custom properties can be used by the clients to search already sent messages.

For example:

1. *Client A* could find SMS messages sent to administrator users in period between [Date 1; Date 2] that have 'alert' status.
2. *Client B* could find all notification sent by specified template.

Of course, data should be fetched page by page.

At first I created the following database model:

[Database scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWyIf.png)

To find all messages with specified properties I tried to use query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT message_id FROM custom_message_properties
                  WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(key, ':'), value) IN ('property1:value1', 'property2:value2')
              GROUP BY message_id having(count(*)) = 2)
              as cmp JOIN message m ON cmp.message_id = m.id ORDER BY ID LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Query worked fine (although it seems me not very good) in database with small data. I decided to check results for ~ real awaited data . 
So i generated 10 000 000 messages that have 40 000 000 custom properties and checked result. Execution time was ~ 2 minutes. The most time consumed operation was following sub-select:

```
SELECT message_id FROM custom_message_properties
                  WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(key, ':'), value) IN ('property1:value1', 'property2:value2')
```

I understand that string comparison is very slow cause database index feature is not used. I decided to change database structure to merge 'key' and 'value' columns into single one. So i updated by database scheme :

[Updated database scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENziG.png)

I checked result again. Now execution time was ~20 seconds. It's much better but still is not suitable for production use.

So now I have no idea how to improve performance without significant changes in application architecture design. 
The only one thought i have is to create separate table for each client with required client properties.

```
client(i)_custom_properties {
      mid bigint, // foreign key references message (id)
      p1  type1,
      p2  type2,
      ......
      pn  type(n)
}
```

I have spent a lot of time while trying to find any useful information. I have also analyzed 'stackoverflow' database cause it seemed me that it should be quite the same. But in 'stackoverflow' there are ~ 50 000 different tags. Not so much that my database could have.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks, in advance!

Project environment that i use :

1. Postgres database  (9.6)
2. Java 1.8
3. Spring modules (spring-boot, spring-data-jpa + hibernate, spring-ws, etc).

Comment: http://www.databasesoup.com/2015/01/tag-all-things.html

Comment: Big thanks for your feedback. I analyzed this article. For my project it will be difficult to use not-jpa things, like postgres array and jsonb data types.
Later I want to build project env. on noSQL data storage (like elastic search or mongodb) and test the same queries.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of ORM - Obfuscated Relational Model

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any suitable solution except creating additional table with client's properties for each client.
I know, that solution is not so flexible, 
but now search query time is less than 1 second.

In future, I will try to solve the same problem using noSQL data storage.

Comment: You don't need a noSQL solution. You just need to get rid of your obfuscation layer that prevents you from using noSQL features in Postgres.